# checking excel row values and return column header in c# winforms

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I currently have program that checks a date that is selected in MonthCalendar and uses it to search through the first column [date] for a matching value before performing a function. This function is to check the rest of the columns among the same row for a certain Value and then returning the column headers that have that Value. How do I do this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();

        string CSVFilePathName = @"pathname.csv";
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
        DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
            dt5.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt5.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
            dt5.Rows.Add(Row);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        {
            Object o = dt5.Rows[i]["date"];
            if (o.ToString() == date)
            {
                (INSERT CODE HERE TO CHECK REST OF COLUMNS ON SAME ROW AND RETURN COLUMN HEADER)  
            }
        }
    }
```

Hi I have now attached the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Excel Interop](https://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) to read an excel file and then search for whatever you want.

You've said that you already have a program that does something. Can you post the code or whatever you've tried so far? It'll help us help you better.